# Undefined number of Payload arguments - RESTful

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json, laravel

I'm building an API in Laravel.

Here's my system:

- In the system there are performances, it's dates and it's prices. So, 3 tables.
- An user can buy tickets to performances. So, another table.

  - An user has to be able to buy at once several tickets of different prices. One more table, Transaction.

What i have right now is an API that accept POST's with the following payloads:

- performance_price_id, performance_id, performance_date_id

So it only accept one ticket per Transaction.

**Problem**: how to adapt this API to accept several **performance_price_id**'s, so that an user can buy for example 5 VIP tickets and 5 normal tickets in a single Transaction(to the same performance at the same date, of course).

Note: there is not a static number of prices per performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using a string with the next format:

```
performance_price_id,performance_date_id;performance_price_id,performance_date_id;...
```

And instead of having undefined number of payload arguments, i have a well-defined number (2), which are 
**performance_id** and **tickets**